# Remove Search this site in sharepoint 2013 using jquery

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, jquery

i have written the below jquery to remove the text “search this site”. it is working fine . but on mouse over it is still showing the old text i.e ” search this site”. Also when I now try to insert a search term I first have to blank out the initial text – it’s not automatically blanked out when selecting the search box. Do you have a fix for this?
Below is my jquery function:

```
$(function() {
var theSearchBox = $(‘#ctl00_PlaceHolderSearchArea_SmallSearchInputBox1_csr_sbox’);
var defaultSearchText = “Search this site”;
var preferredSearchText = “Search the Homepage Content”;
//replace the text initially
theSearchBox.val(preferredSearchText);
theSearchBox.focus(function() {
if ($(this).val().indexOf(defaultSearchText) > -1)
$(this).val(preferredSearchText);
});
theSearchBox.blur(function() {
if ($(this).val().indexOf(defaultSearchText) > -1)
$(this).val(preferredSearchText);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative and recommended way to change the search box's prompt is to make changes to the master page or modify the 'Control_SearchBox_Compact.html' display template. Modification to the master page is the easiest options since you're only looking to change the initial prompt. This involves replacing the delegate control for the search with a web part control.

1- Add the following to your master page:

```
<%@Register TagPrefix="SearchWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>
```

2- Replace the search delegate control
Replace

```
<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox" />
```

with

```
<SearchWC:SearchBoxScriptWebPart UseSiteCollectionSettings="true" EmitStyleReference="false" ShowQuerySuggestions="false" ChromeType="None" UseSharedSettings="true" TryInplaceQuery="false" ServerInitialRender="true" runat="server" InitialPrompt="Your Custom Text Goes Here"></SearchWC:SearchBoxScriptWebPart>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi on mouse over it would show tool tip for the control, check whether the control have a attribute called 'title' if so change the content of the attribute with the required value like

```
theSearchBox.attr('title',preferredSearchText);
```

include the above line in your jquery probably it would change the text on mouse over.

Comment: That's Cool :-). Can you please tell me how to solve when I try to insert a search term I first have to blank out the initial text – it’s not automatically blanked out when selecting the search box.

Comment: hi you can remove the content on focus of the control and replace the content if no values are entered the below code would help you `theSearchBox.attr('onfocus','if(this.value=='+preferredSearchText+'){this.value="";}');` and for onblur to insert the content if nothing is entered `theSearchBox.attr('onfocus','if(this.value==""){this.value='+preferredSearchText+';}');`

Comment: place both the line in document ready function

Answer (score 0):

Now a days almost all browser support HTML5. So why not we take advantage of it

```
theSearchBox.attr("placeholder",preferredSearchText);
```

hope it will help you.